# How SVGs are able to incoporate effects like blur?

Tags: image, svg, raster, effect

I have been familiar with the SVG format since a long time. It's usability and benefits over a raster image as well.

But Recently I came to a situation where I needed blur effect in SVG(basically a asset defined by primitive shapes that mimics blur effect and is infinitely scalable), so I did a google search and much to my surprise there are official ways of doing it; I was expecting it not to be!

I am basically intrigued by the fact that if SVGs are really made up primitives shapes defined mathematically then how can it incorporate effect like blur. What shape can even be used for such a process?

Comment: You can define blur mathematically - otherwise you wouldn't be able to blur raster images either.

Comment: SVG's vector shapes are eventually rendered as pixels.  SVG filters, like blur, just modify those pixels at that final stage.

Comment: Oh, so it's just simple blur, nothing fancy going on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox we render the SVG to an offscreen surface, blur the pixels on that surface and then blit the offscreen surface. I imagine other browsers work similarly.

Filters and masks are raster operations, most everything else is vector.